# Bash Script output to rest api call

Tags: linux, bash

I need to monitor a Linux server using bash script so scenario is like this

1. I have a bash script which can monitor a Linux service and it shows
   result right
2. Now I need to show the result of bash script to port
   8080 or any port like http://192.168.2.1:8080 and it will show
   status code 200 or error, So when I hit http://192.168.2.1:8080 it will execute the bash script and get result and show it

Note: No web service is running right now on server

Comment: You will need a minimal http server implementation. You can use netcat, for example.

Comment: Ok what I did is "python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000 &" in my directory put my output in .html file

Comment: I like your approach :) Why don't you use pipes to implement interaction between your bash script and the python server?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using CGI. There go some links:

- Setup apache: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html
- Shell scripts: http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialCgiShellScript.html
- If you need to grab GET / POST parameters: https://marc.waeckerlin.org/computer/blog/parsing_of_query_string_in_bash_cgi_scripts

Regards,

Comment: I think apache is a bit of overkill in this situation. He does not need to manage virtual hosts, create directory aliases, or any of the services apache provides, except parsing the request type and the URI (not even the headers I guess), which can easily be achieved even in a shell script. I know it's charming to do it the way above, but it's superfluous to use such a powerful tool.